# adb push: where did the files go?

Tags: android, adb

I have created a very simple android app to test `adb push`. I am basically trying to view a list of files stored in the data directory. Using `adb push` to add files, I was expecting to see the list change, but although the files show up the *DDMS Perspective*, they are not in the data directory that my app is looking at (and thus the `Activity is displaying *EMPTY*, as shown in the code below). What is the correct path I should be pushing to, or what am I doing wrong?

**The code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(updateView());
    }

    public View updateView() {
        File[] files = Environment.getDataDirectory().listFiles();
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)    this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text01);
        String s = "";
        if (files != null) {
            for (File f : files) {
                s += f.getName() + "\n";
            }
        }
        else {
            s = "EMPTY";
        }
        tv.setText(s);
        return v;
    }
}
```

**The command:**

```
./adb push myfile.txt /data/myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't access `/data` without root permission. You should add your files to `Activity.getFilesDir()` which translates to `/data/data/com.yourapp/files`

Comment: Actually, `getFilesDir()` typically maps to `/data/data/com.yourapp/files/`.